# Where can I find a proper repository of OpenModelica syntax?

Tags: simulation, openmodelica, systemdynamics

I have been exploring Open Modelica for a week for system Dynamics. All though I learned few basic things(like function and class syntax etc..) from Spoken Tutorial, I need to go a long way. I am not to find a proper source mentioning the syntaxes for various aspects. For example, I am not able to find syntax for writing derivatives(dy/dx) apart from the time derivative[ der(x)]. Is there someplace where I can look into for further proceeding?

P.s. I am new to Softwares like MATLAB, Octave etc.. and OpenModelica is my first one.

Answer (score 0):

OpenModelica is a Modelica tool. All Modelica related resources, e.g. language specification, can be found here: https://www.modelica.org/